# Language selection add products in multistore Opencart

Tags: opencart, product

Please help.
Operated multistore with multiple languages​​. One shop in English and a second store in the Czech language.
I need to add a product in the store 1Only in English and shop 2 only in Czech language.
By default OC is fill in the details in all languages ​​allowed. I do not.
Please give to modify the code as admin / controller / catalog / product.php validateForm?
Thank you for your help.
Sorry for my English

Answer (score 0):

You have to write condition for your store_ids and their corresponding language id's with in the foreach loop in validateForm function:

```
foreach ($this->request->post['product_description'] as $language_id => $value) {
if(//condition to check Czech storeid and Czech language id){
  ....
  //validate conditions
  ....
}else{
  ....
  //engish validate conditions
  ....
}
}
```